# How can I check which specific users have logged into a specific PC using AD (Win2008 R2)?

Tags: windows

I need to list all users logged into a certain PC, couldn't find anything close using the Active Directory.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you asking all of them logged in 'currently', or all of them logged in withing a specific time range.  Define logged in.  Do you mean they are at the console using it.  Or do you mean accessing it over the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If [logging is enabled](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758201%28WS.10%29.aspx), then go look at the security log on that machine.  If you merge all the security logs from all the domain controllers, then you should also be able to see who authenticated to the domain from which workstation.

Comment: Great the security log gives me everything I need.